# Sharepoint Foundation 2013: single cpu

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, cpu

Have SharePoint Foundation spinning on a Windows Server 2012 R2.

VM is equipped with 4 CPUs and 20 GB of RAM.

It looks SharePoint is only using 25%, single CPU. Where to change this setting?

[image: cpu stats]

Comment: SharePoint is a set of very much running processes and services. Please look inside the VM and check TaskManager. Would be interesting to see, which process is limited to one CPU-Core.

Comment: wsstracing.exe is 25%

Answer (score 1):

wsstracing.exe is the service responsible for SharePoint logging. Such a high CPU-Usage for logging-service is not normal.

Some things to check:

- Go to SharePoint `Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Configure diagnostic logging` -> Check if any Categories are set to `Verbose` logging. Reset them to their defaults with the option `Least critical event to report to the trace log`
- Restart the `SharePoint Tracing Service (SPTracev4)` in Windows Services Console (`services.msc`)
- You might see the following errors in your [ULS-Log](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/use-uls-log-viewer-with-sharepoint-server-2016): `Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.` This happens if the service account does not have proper permissions to logging-directory.

  - First get the correct user in `services.msc`:
    [image: WSS Tracing Service-User]
  - This account should be a member in the following local groups: `WSS_ADMIN_WPG` and `WSS_WPG`
    [image: Tracing Groups]
  - Get the ULS-Logging path in `Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Configure diagnostic logging`:
    [image: ULS-Log Path]
  - Check if permissions are correctly set on the logging folder. Both groups should have `read`, `write` and some `special permissions`: 
    [image]